# Network request failed - Expo React Native

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, react-native, expo

This is really annoying me. if i use http://my-domain.com its work with out  Network request failed, but https://my-domain.com its keep giving me Network request failed error.

i been looking online and still not fix this issue. Please help.

**package.json**

```
"dependencies": {
"@expo/vector-icons": "~10.0.6",
"@react-native-community/masked-view": "0.1.6",
"@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^5.0.0",
"@react-navigation/native": "^5.0.0",
"@react-navigation/stack": "^5.0.0",
"@react-navigation/web": "~1.0.0-alpha.9",
"expo": "~37.0.3",
"expo-asset": "~8.1.3",
"expo-constants": "~9.0.0",
"expo-font": "~8.1.0",
"expo-web-browser": "~8.1.0",
"react": "~16.9.0",
"react-dom": "~16.9.0",
"react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-37.0.1.tar.gz",
"react-native-gesture-handler": "~1.6.0",
"react-native-iphone-x-helper": "^1.2.1",
"react-native-modalize": "^1.3.7-rc.19",
"react-native-safe-area-context": "0.7.3",
"react-native-screens": "~2.2.0",
"react-native-web": "~0.11.7"
```

},

**Fetch code**

```
const [contents, setContents] = useState([]);

const fetchChannelContent = (slug) => {
    fetch(Http.api+"/channel/"+slug)
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((json) => {
            setContents(json.channel.content);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.error(error);
        });
};

useEffect(() => {
    fetchChannelContent(url)
}, []);[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

[1]:

Http Class

```
export default {
api: "https://my-domain.com"
```

}

Comment: try using axios. It doesn't require https

Comment: I had use all type package to make sure which one used but every one is same. and the url i used its has https and i have to use that as my required. @Bryan

Comment: what happens if you directly type the address on the fetch?

Comment: directly type Its worked @Bryan

Comment: I put the http.js. please the updated code and please what did wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
export default url {
api: "https://my-domain.com"
}
```

Then you import that file and user url.api

Comment: I have exactly like that then import in the fetch.js import Http from "../../utils/Http"; call Http.api